# How to pass query statement to bigquery in node.js environment

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

During the big query, the parameters of the function in the SQL statement
I want to update the result of a sql statement by inserting it as @ variable name.
However, there is no method to support node.js.

For python, there are methods like the following example.
You can use the function's parameters as @ variable names.

```
query = "" "
SELECT word, word_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
WHERE corpus = @ corpus
AND word_count> = @min_word_count
ORDER BY word_count DESC;"" "
query_params = [
bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter ('corpus', 'STRING', 'romeoandjuliet'),
bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter ('min_word_count', 'INT64', 250)]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig ()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params
```

related document:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery-query-params-python

I would like to ask for advice.

Comment: The fact there is no javascript example in the link provided doesn't means the @ is not supported via javascript client lib in node.js. The @ is a property of the sql process on bigquery side. Please try this using javascript sql client and if it doesn't work post the code and the error message you get... Good luck.

Comment: Use this [link] (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query) which explain how to set job.query with a parameter object

Comment: One option is to use API to connect & query through node js https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery-query-params-api (you can try it in the API explorer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

BigQuery node.js client supports parameterized queries when you pass them with the params key in options. Just updated [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery-query-params-nodejs) to show this. Hope this helps!

Example:

```
const sqlQuery = `SELECT word, word_count
      FROM \`bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare\`
      WHERE corpus = @corpus
      AND word_count >= @min_word_count
      ORDER BY word_count DESC`;

const options = {
  query: sqlQuery,
  // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
  location: 'US',
  params: {corpus: 'romeoandjuliet', min_word_count: 250},
};

// Run the query
const [rows] = await bigquery.query(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth adding that you can create a stored procedure and pass parameters the same way as the accepted answer shows.

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');


function testProc() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {   

  const bigquery = new BigQuery();
  const sql = "CALL `my-project.my-dataset.getWeather`(@dt);";

  const options = {
  query: sql,
  params: {dt: '2022-09-01'},
  location: 'US'
  };

  // Run the query
  const result = bigquery.query(options);

  return result.then((rows) => {
    console.log(rows);
    resolve(rows);
  });
  
  });
} 

testProc().catch((err) => { console.error(JSON.stringify(helpers.getError(err.message))); });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let ip_chunk = "'1.2.3.4', '2.3.4.5', '10.20.30.40'"
let query = `
  SELECT 
    ip_address.ip as ip,
    instance.zone as zone,
    instance.name as vmName,
    instance.p_name as projectName
  FROM 
    \`${projectId}.${datasetId}.${tableId}\` instance, 
    UNNEST(field_x.DATA.some_info) ip_address 
  WHERE ip_address.networkIP IN (${ip_chunk})`

**Use - WHERE ip_address.networkIP in (${ip_chunk})
instead of - WHERE ip in (${ip_chunk})**
```